# Why is my program not calculating flips correctly when run multiple times?

Tags: python, python-3.11

First off I'm very new to Python and I'm making this as part of a course. I'm totally stumped so thought this might be a good opportunity to try using Stack Overflow.

I'm trying to make a program that asks the user to flip a coin, and enter the result.
The program will then calculate how many times they've flipped heads or tails, and what percentage of times they got heads.

To do this it reads and writes to a text file to update some variables, and uses those variables for the calculations.

When I clear the file `"flip_results.txt"` so it's blank, the program runs as expected first time through. The problem is when I rerun it, it starts to get everything wrong.

So I assume there is something wrong with the file reading part in `def count_flips():` but I have no idea what.

Here is the code:

```
def count_flips():
    # Open the text file.
    with open("flip_results.txt", "r") as file:
        # Read the file into a list.
        lines = file.readlines()
        # Define the variables starting at zero.
        heads_count = 0
        tails_count = 0
        # Loop through the list, and update the variables based on the number of "h" heads or "t" tails.
        for line in lines:
            if line.strip().lower() == "h":
                heads_count += 1
            elif line.strip().lower() == "t":
                tails_count += 1
    # Define the total number of flips as the sum of heads and tails.
    total_flips = heads_count + tails_count
    # Return the variables for use below in the while loop.
    return heads_count, tails_count, total_flips

total_flips, heads_count, tails_count = count_flips()

while True:
    # Get user input and strip it of whitespace.
    result = input("Flip a coin (Enter 'H' for heads or 'T' for tails): ")
    result = result.strip().lower()
    # Check if the user input is "h" or "t".
    if result == "h":
        # If it's heads, print heads, and write "h" to the file.
        print("Heads!")
        with open("flip_results.txt", "a") as file:
            file.write("h \n")
        # Update the variables.
        total_flips += 1
        heads_count += 1
        # Calculate the percentage anRd print it.
        print(f"You have flipped heads {heads_count} times out of {total_flips}.")
        print(f"You have flipped heads {heads_count / total_flips * 100}% of your flips.")

    elif result == "t":
        print("Tails!")
        with open("flip_results.txt", "a") as file:
            file.write("t \n")
        # Update the variables.
        total_flips += 1
        tails_count += 1
        # Calculate the percentage and print it.
        print(f"You have flipped tails {tails_count} times out of {total_flips}.")
        print(f"You have flipped heads {heads_count / total_flips * 100}% of your flips.")
    else:
        print("Invalid input. Try again.")
        continue
```

Thanks for any insights! Hope this question is ok :)

I'll give an example of how it's messed up.

I clear the .txt file and run the program.
I enter T, T, T, H, H, H, and it gives correct answers each time, ending with saying...
`You have flipped heads 3 times out of 6.`
`You have flipped head 50% of your flips.`

Then I end the program, and rerun it.

No I enter T.

It says:

You have flipped tails 7 times out of 4.
You have flipped heads 75.0% of your flips.

flip_results.txt shows:

```
t 
t 
t 
h 
h 
h 
t
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `total_flips, heads_count, tails_count = count_flips()` should be `heads_count, tails_count,total_flips = count_flips()` You have your return values in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to flip the variables to match the return from `count_flips()` :

```
heads_count, tails_count, total_flips = count_flips()
```

This should mirror the return statement:
`return heads_count, tails_count, total_flips`